# How to scroll two QVBoxLayout objects which live inside a QHBoxLayout

Tags: widget, qt5, scrollbar

I built an app without Qt Creator a while ago, and I am working to update it a bit. What I want in this instance is to be able to have unique widget heights in a vertical scrolling UI. I have the UI working, but not the scrolling.

[image: Current UI]

```cpp
void TabWidget::newTab(QString topic, QJsonDocument doc)
{
    QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout();        // Parent horizontal layout for the Verts
    m_leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout();          // Left side VBoxLayout
    m_rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout();         // Right side VBoxLayout
    QWidget *leftWidget = new QWidget();       // Owner of the left VBox
    QWidget *rightWidget = new QWidget();      // Owner of the right VBox
    leftWidget->setLayout(m_leftLayout);       
    rightWidget->setLayout(m_rightLayout);
    l->addWidget(leftWidget);                  // Sets left widget into the HBoxLayout
    l->addWidget(rightWidget);                 // Sets the right widget into the layout
    setLayout(l);                              // TabWidget* has layout as it's layout
    QScrollArea *sa = new QScrollArea();       // Wrap it all in a Scroller
    sa->setWidget(this);                       // This widget is controlled by the scroller

    JsonWidget *widget = new JsonWidget(topic);
    m_widgets[topic] = widget;
    widget->addJson(doc);
    m_leftLayout->addWidget(widget);
    m_whichSide = layoutSide::RIGHT;
}
```

```cpp
void MQTTSnoopWindow::newTab(QString topic, QJsonDocument json)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&m_newTabMutex);
    QString parentTopic = topic.left(topic.indexOf("/"));
    TabWidget *tab = new TabWidget();
    tab->newTab(topic, json);
    m_tabWidget->addTab(tab, parentTopic);
    m_topics++;
}
```

The `TabWidget` lives in a QTabWidget, which calls `newTab` on my `TabWidget*` instance, and then sets this object into the QTabWidget parent.

I've tested with and without the `JsonWidget` calling `setMinimumHeight(h + 20);` calculated on the number of rows in the QTreeView. One grows the entire app frame, the other shrinks the widgets.

The embedded JSON widgets are a QLabel and QTreeView containing a QModel, courtesy of the https://github.com/dridk/QJsonModel.

If I enforce a minimum height for the `JsonWidget`, then the window grows, no scroller is added. I expect this is due to the nesting, but I can't figure out how to get the effect of different height widgets side by side another way.

Note, that if I do this with a single QGridLayout instead of the QHBox and QVBox inside that, the scroller works, but I lose the sizing I want. The two QVBoxLayout objects are members of the class, so I could do some debug/checks in other functions, I don't actually use them otherwise.